# Is it possible to get indices from x values in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have a data set containing dates (x values). Later in the code I need to get index of the array element which contains that date. Is it possible to get a particular index of the array according to date input?

Data set:

```
{"date": "2006-12-01", "POPYFR": "6.32296e+07", "status": {}}, {"date": "2007-12-01", "POPYFR": "6.36451e+07", "status": {}
```

So if I have a date 2006-12-01 the function should return 0 etc.

Comment: Explain *how* do you want to get the indices. Depending on the method you're using, it can be as simple as using a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using d3 try bisector or bisect
https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-bisect

```
const data = {"date": "2006-12-01", "POPYFR": "6.32296e+07", "status": {}}, {"date": "2007-12-01", "POPYFR": "6.36451e+07", "status": {}

bisect = d3.bisector(d => moment(d.date, "YYYY-MM-DD").toDate())
const value = bisect(data, "2006-12-01");
```

Answer (score -2):

Is there a reason you can't just iterate over the data? Something like

```
indexOfDate(date) {
  for (var i=0; i<dataSet.length; i++) {
    if (dataSet[i].date === date) return i;
  }  
  return -1;
}
```

?